# ¿ Cómo creo un componente en webix que sea un agregado de varios?

Tags: javascript, webix

Quiero crear un control para mostrar mi propio *teclado virtual* en la ventana del navegador. Sin embargo, al tratar de generar un componente exclusivo para mostrarlo, pues *como que no va*.

En un principio, durante las pruebas, solo quiero mostrar una matriz de `3 * 3` botones. El código *aislado* (sin ser un *componente*), para generar el resultado que espero conseguir, es el siguiente:

```js
webix.ready( function( ) {
  var w = 50,
      h = 50,
      s = 10;

  webix.ui( {
      rows: [
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        },
        { height: s },
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        },
        { height: s },
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        }
      ]
    } )
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js"></script>
```

Aparte de la documentación oficial de `webix` (en inglés) [Creating a Custom Component](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__custom_component.html), he encontrado [un *snippet* al respecto](http://webix.com/snippet/744a608d), que hace lo que yo quiero: crea un componente, que es un *agregado* de varios componentes menores. Al incluir aquí el código, muestra un aviso, pero **no es relevante**: se debe al cambio de página de *soporte*, de la oficial de `webix` a los `stack-snippets`.

He *limpiado* todo lo que he podido del código original; ha perdido toda su funcionalidad, pero el aspecto gráfico sigue idéntico:

```js
webix.protoUI({
  name: "dndlist",
  defaults: {
label: "",
labelWidth: 80,
height: 200,
choicesHeader: "Choices",
valueHeader: "Selected",
choices: [],
value: [],
swap: false
  },
  $formElement: true,
  $init: function (cfg) {
var dnd = this;
config = webix.extend(this.defaults, cfg, true);

var dtCommon = {view: "datatable", scrollX: false, drag: true};
var value = [];
for (var i = 0; i < config.value.length; i++) {
  value.push({value: config.value[i]});
}
var choicesDt = webix.extend(webix.copy(dtCommon), {
  id: 'choices',
  columns: [
   {
    id: "value",
    header: {
     text: config.choicesHeader,
     colspan: 2
    },
    fillspace: true
   },
   {
    id: "_actions",
    header: "&nbsp;",
    width: 35,
    template: function (row) {
     return "<span  style=' cursor:pointer;' class='webix_icon fa-plus-square'></span>";
    }
   }
  ],
  onClick: {
   'fa-plus-square': function (e, i) {
    var row = this.getItem(i.row);
    dnd.addValue(row.value);
   }
  },
  on: {
   onItemDblClick: function (id) {
    dnd.addValue(this.getItem(id).value);
   }
  }
 }, true);
 var valueDt = webix.extend(webix.copy(dtCommon), {
  id: 'value',
  columns: [
   {
    id: "value",
    header: {
     text: config.valueHeader,
     colspan: 2
    },
    fillspace: true
   },
   {
    id: "_actions",
    header: "&nbsp;",
    width: 35,
    template: function (row) {
     return "<span  style=' cursor:pointer;' class='webix_icon fa-minus-square'></span>";
    }
   }
  ],
  onClick: {
   'fa-minus-square': function (e, i) {
    var row = this.getItem(i.row);
    dnd.removeValue(row.value);
   }
  },
  on: {
   onItemDblClick: function (id) {
    dnd.removeValue(this.getItem(id).value);
   }
  }
 }, true);

 var spacer = {view: 'spacer', width: 10};
 var cols = {cols: (config.swap ? [valueDt, spacer, choicesDt] : [choicesDt, spacer, valueDt])};
 var label = {view: 'label', label: config.label, width: config.labelWidth, align: config.labelAlign};

 if (config.labelPosition === 'top') {
  config.rows = [
   label,
   cols
  ];
 } else {
  label.css = {padding: "1px 7.5px 0px 5px"};
  config.cols = [
   {
    rows: [label]
   },
   cols
  ];
 }

 this.$ready.push(function () {
  // this.setValue(config.value);
  // this.setChoices(config.choices);
 });
}
}, webix.IdSpace, webix.ui.layout);

webix.ui( {
  view: "form",
  width: "100%",
  elements: [
   {
  view: "text",
  name: "name",
  label: "Name",
  value: "Unknown"
},
{
  view: "dndlist",
  name: "attributes",
  label: "Attributes",
  choices: [ "Tall", "Handsome", "Rich", "Kind", "Hardworking", "Romantic" ],
  value: [ "Handsome" ]
}
  ]
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js"></script>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Eso es mas o menos lo que estoy buscando hacer: crear un componente que sea un *agregado* de otros mas simples.

El funcionamiento del código, hasta donde puedo seguirlo, es crear un componente, *heredando* de `webix.IdSpace` y `webix.ui.layout`. Proporciona un método `$init` que es llamado para inicializar el control una vez que este se crea.

En dicha inicialización, se limita a rellenar un objeto `config`; *presumo* que ese objeto es el que utiliza el módulo `webix.ui.layout`, del cual heredamos, para mostrar los controles que le indicamos.

Bueno, pues ya llegamos. Lo que estoy intentado es

```js
webix.protoUI( {
  name: 'test',
  $formElement: true,
  $init: function( cfg ) {
    var x3 = this,
        s,
        h,
        w;

    cfg = cfg || { };
    s = cfg.space || 10;
    h = cfg.height || 50;
    w = cfg.width || 50;

    config = {
      rows: [
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        },
        { height: s },
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        },
        { height: s },
        { cols: [
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          { width: s },
          { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}, webix.IdSpace, webix.ui.layout );

webix.ready( function( ) {
  webix.ui( {
    rows: [
      { },
      { cols: [
          { },
          { view: 'test' },
          { }
        ]
      },
      { }
    ]
  } );
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js"></script>
```

Al probarlo en el navegador, me genera un *bonito*

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined webix_debug.js:5894`

Como muestro al principio de la pregunta, en el primer trozo de código, probado de forma aislada, funciona correctamente y muestra la matriz de `3 * 3`.

Comment: Pasé el primer bloque al stack-snippet en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1892/65 . Devuelve un error indicando que `webix` no está definido. Antes de agregar el código a stack-snippet en esta pregunta, lo primero sería identificar si existe una librería de webix para para cargar en IDE, si esta fuera javascript puro y no un plug-in, se podría incluir pero en caso contrario, no tendría sentido usar stack-snippet pues el código no se podría ejecutar.

Comment: @Rubén gracias por intentar pasarlo a snippets. Los bloques 1 y 2 funcionan perfectamente en `localhost`, y el 3 da el error que indico. En mi intento de usar `stack-snippets` obtuve el mismo resultado que tú: `webix` no está definido. En los 3 bloques. Fíjate que uso `cdn`, por lo que deben funcionar en cualquier máquina. En cuanto al `parloteo`, intenté describir el problema lo mejor que pude, con los pasos exactos que he seguido, ya que , como indico, no he visto preguntas sobre `webix` y no estoy seguro de la causa del error. Edita y elimina, o dime que partes crees que sobran.

Comment: @Rubén Agradezco la edición. Lo tendré en cuenta para el futuro. Consulto la pregunta en *meta* que indicas, a ver si puedo generar unos *snippets* que funcionen, eliminando las imágenes. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad, es fácil, una vez que le *cogemos el tranquillo* al asunto.

Primero, mi error:

```
$init: function( cfg ) {
  ...
  config = {
    rows: [
      { cols: [
        { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
        { width: s },
        { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
        { width: s },
        { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
        ]
      },
      {
      ...
  };
  ...
}
```

Ahí, en la función `$init` de inicialización del componente, **creo** una nueva variable `config`, **en lugar de usar la que recibo como argumento**.

Cuando `webix` lee mi *objeto de descripción*, en las llamadas a `webix.ui( ... )`, crea un objeto `config` con unos datos que ella misma necesita para su funcionamiento interno.

Ese objeto **lo recibimos como argumento** en nuestra función `$init( )`. Ahí, podemos modificarlo **lo que queramos**, siempre y cuando que **respetemos** unos atributos **desconocidos para nosotros**. Dicho objeto de configuración es **reenviado** a los distintos módulos de los que *heredamos*; aquellos que incluimos en nuestra llamada a `webix.protoUI( ... )`. En el caso expuesto, dichos módulos son `webix.ui.layout` y `webix.IdSpace`.

La solución consiste en modificar **tan solo aquellos datos que sean usados por los módulos de los que heredamos**. Para ello, no tenemos mas que consultar las distintas APIs, y fijarnos en la sección `Properties`.

Para mi componente `pinkeyboard`, establezco unos *argumentos* **como si mi componente fuera, en realidad, un `webix.ui.layout`**.

Al terminar la ejecución de mi función `$init`, el argumento `config` que recibimos **es reutilizado** por la llamada (oculta para nosotros, `webix` se encarga de ella internamente) a los módulos *padres* de nuestro componente.

El resultado final es el siguiente:

```js
webix.protoUI( {
  name: 'pinkeyboard',
  defaults: { },
  //$formElement: true,
  $init: function( config ) {
var s,
    h,
    w,
    tmp;

s = config.space || 10;
h = config.height || 50;
w = config.width || 50;

webix.extend( config, {
  rows: [
{ cols: [
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
    { width: s },
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
    { width: s },
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
  ]
},
{ height: s },
{ cols: [
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
    { width: s },
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
    { width: s },
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
  ]
},
{ height: s },
{ cols: [
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
    { width: s },
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
    { width: s },
    { view: 'button', width: w, height: h },
  ]
}
  ]
} );

  }
}, webix.IdSpace, webix.ui.layout );

webix.ui( {
  rows: [
{ },
{ cols: [
    { },
    { view: 'pinkeyboard' },
    { }
  ]
},
{ }
  ]
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js"></script>
```

Como se observa, una matriz de `3 * 3` botones, **usando mi componente personalizado `pinkeyboard`**.

Estos pasos **son comunes** para cualquier componente *personalizado* que necesitemos crear. Podemos cambiar algunos atributos por defecto, o crear un componente *nuevo* mediante la agregación de varios, o, por ejemplo, crear una barra de herramientas con un conjunto de componentes internos *listos para usar*.